# Stackoverflow in Pentaho

Tags: loops, stack-overflow, pentaho, kettle

I have an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I have a job (A) that calls another job (B). Iteration takes place in job B. There is a loop inside job B which reads one row at a time from a source file and writes to a text file.

Problem is the source file contains 37,000 rows but the execution stops at row 27,000. It crashes and gives me

> "ERROR (version 6.0.0.0-353, build 1 from 2015-10-07 13.27.43 by
>   buildguy) : java.lang.StackOverflowError"

I have tried to gradually increase the stack in spoon.bat from 1g to 7g `"-Xms7g" "-Xmx12g" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` but continues to crash. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this helps:
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-1463

Comment: Seb, thanks for the link. I have checked it but dont actualy understand what i should be doing. i am using the latest release of pentaho and from what i understand is that the problem has been fixed in this version.

Comment: There is another case, being Open now: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7453. But since it was reported for 4.5 I'm not sure it is actual now. @Niki, can you share you jobs? It will be helpful

Comment: I would love to post the project here but i dont know how to do it! i dont have enough points to attach the files. I have solved the problem. it was a thread issue. i added one parameter to my spoon.bat "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2048m" "-Xmx4096m" "-Xss512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Answer (score 1):

I finaly solved the the problem, i added one parameter ("-Xss512m") to my spoon.bat "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2048m" "-Xmx4096m" "-Xss512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"